# how do I get last commit SVN log with modified files list and commit message?

Tags: svn, revision

I have just commit the the code and I forgot to save revision log and file list I have committed. can anybody provide the command so I can get full information of last log that is.

1. modified files list
2. revision number
3. commit message

I have tried below command but i can't see the modified file list

```
svn log -r1:HEAD

------------------------------------------------------------------------
revision | my id | 2016-03-25 03:18:38 -0500 (Fri, 25 Mar 2016) | 1 line

my message
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After commit the code, I executed below commands and get as expected result

```
svn update
svn log --limit 1 -v
```

here `svn update` command will update your local repository and `svn log --limit 1` will show your last commit history and the option `-v` will the file list with you have added, modified or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The revision number and commit message is already in the default output of `svn log`, and included in the example in your question too. So the only missing is the list of modified files.

Add the `-v` parameter:

```
svn log -v
```

That way the output will include the list of changed paths, prefixed with the action on the path, for example `A` for added, `M` for modified, `D` for deleted.